# when will getAsText() in PropertyEditorSupport called or invoke

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I am using spring 3 mvc

try to rewrite PropertyEditorSupport for my initBinder. setAsText() is working fine. But i have a look some of example online. they override getAsText() too.

So when getAsText() is called. what is usage of getAsText()? any example or use case

thx

Answer (score 0):

getAsText is used to format a field value in AbstractPropertyBindingResult (part of spring validation).  So I suspect that if you don't used Spring Validation, not having getAsText will not impact you.

Comment: could plz provide some example or link? thank you for ur reply.

Comment: Your getAsText should do the reverse of setAsText... it would be easier if you posted your code.